# Create an array of users based on each user's weekday and time attributes

Tags: ruby, datetime, range

I have the following code which creates an array of users depending on the "global" weekdays and times.

```
def current_time
  # server_time = Time.now
  server_time = Time.local(2013,8,19,8,30) # for time simulation
  local_offset = (2 * 60 * 60)
  local_time = server_time + local_offset
end

def hours_mon_to_thurs?(date)
    ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"].include?(date.strftime("%A")) && ("08:30"..."17:00").include?(date.strftime("%H:%M"))
end

def hours_fri?(date)
    ["Friday"].include?(date.strftime("%A")) && ("08:30"..."15:00").include?(date.strftime("%H:%M"))
end

def hours_lunch?(date)
    !("12:00"..."13:00").include?(date.strftime("%H:%M"))
end


if hours_mon_to_thurs?(current_time) && hours_lunch?(current_time)
  p "[USER1, USER2]"
elsif hours_fri?(current_time) && hours_lunch?(current_time)
  p "USER2"
else
  p "no users"
end
```

This code works, but I would like to change how the array is created, so that each user has workdays and times as attributes and if they are available then they should be added to the array. Let me provide an example.

**User 1 - Office Hours**

Monday
08:30 - 12:00,
13:00 - 17:00

Tuesday
08:30 - 12:00,
13:00 - 17:00

Wednesday
08:30 - 12:00,
13:00 - 17:00

Thursday
08:30 - 12:00,
13:00 - 17:00

**User 2 - Office Hours**

Tuesday
08:30 - 12:00,
13:00 - 17:00

Thursday
08:30 - 12:00,
13:00 - 17:00

Friday
08:30 - 12:00,
13:00 - 15:00

With each user's office hours defined I want to have a similar method as in my example above. Something like this:

- for each user
- if current time is within user's office hours
- add user to array
- else if current time is not within users' office hours
- array is empty

I'm not using a database at the moment and I don't know the best way to structure each user's office hours in such a way as to match if the current time is within a user's time range and then add them to an array.

Comment: There is unlcear thinking here. First of all `"08:30"..."17:00"` includes the strings `08:30` to `08:99`, `09:30` to `09:99` etc. However this will not stop your design working. Secondly `!("08:30"..."15:00")` raises a warning and always returns `false`. That isn't what you want. Also, you're not allowing for different times worked on different days. You should describe exactly what result you are trying to get, and go from there.

Comment: @Borodin I've tried to clarify the result I'm trying to get. Hopefully it makes more sense now.